# Sending post request to website

Tags: java, html, http, post, web

I'm trying to use java to log in to a website and then eventually retrieve the cookie in order to gain access to information on the site. It seems my post request is working but I am receiving a response code of 500. I was wondering if this is because I have formatted the post data incorrectly

When using the website it says the post is formatted as below

```
{userName: "dfh", password: "suyj"}
```

In my code I have used this

```
String urlParameters = "userName:dfh,Password:suyj";

    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();
```

Am I right in thinking this could be the issue, and if so how can I correct my post data format?

Below is my whole code

```
public  class post {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0";


    String url = "website";
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    //add reuqest header
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    con.setRequestProperty("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
    con.setRequestProperty("Referer", "https://extbasicph05.podc.sl.edst.ibm.com/FFAMobileRelay/");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "64");
    con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
    con.setRequestProperty("Referer", "https://extbasicph05.podc.sl.edst.ibm.com/FFAMobileRelay/");
    con.setRequestProperty("Cookies", "UnicaNIODID=KGew34gcvZ5-Y2NoBQr; mmid=-1658088866%7CKAAAAAr15Tc8FgsAAA%3D%3D; mmcore.pd=1484641984%7CejEyAAoBQvXlNzwWCxPPXGheAVibftSXgNJIDwAAADoOVvoDstFIAAAAAP//////////AAZEaXJlY3QBFgwIAAYABQAAAAAAAP+MAACAigAA/4wAAAIAxDEAAABFBVUW6QsA/////wHpCxoM//83AAAAAAAAAAOSfwAAusgAAJN/AAAgyAAAlH8AACHIAAABIYAAAAIAAADVNgAAAPcCB+70CwD/////AfQLHQz//60CAAEAAAAAAX+KAAAp2gAAAoCKAABAWBAAgYoAALMAAAAAAAABRQ%3D%3D; mmcore.srv=ldnvwcgus03; IBM_W3SSO_ACCESS=w3-03.sso.ibm.com; CoreID6=32675392371714128784599&ci=51040000|IBMTEST_51040000|IBMTESTW3_50200000|IBMTESTWWW; CoreM_State=75~-1~-1~-1~-1~3~3~5~3~3~7~7~|~~|~~|~~|~||||||~|~~|~~|~~|~~|~~|~~|~~|~; CoreM_State_Content=6~|~EE9EDB09923CD77F~|~0; PrefID=222-11978519; CSList=23427744/17540903,0/0,0/0,0/0,0/0; _ga=GA1.2.233924805.1433836377; mmcore.tst=0.169; ibmSurvey=1435758135373; 50200000_clogin=v=1&l=1435758136&e=1435760174616");

    String urlParameters = "userName:dfh,Password:suyj";

    // Send post request
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
    System.out.println(con.getErrorStream());

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    //print result
    System.out.println(response.toString());

}

}
```

Comment: Usually form parameters are url-encoded into the POST body, like "name1=value1&name2=value2". You can use the network tab under Chrome developer tools/firebug/etc to see exactly what's being sent.

Comment: I used that tap to find {userName: "dfh", password: "suyj"} should I be looking at something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already found out your problem. Just fix it...
Instead of `String urlParameters = "userName:dfh,Password:suyj";`, use

```
String urlParameters = "{userName:\"dfh\",Password:\"suyj\"}";
```

Though I believe your server expects JSON formatted post parameter. In that case you should use,

```
String urlParameters = "{\"userName\":\"dfh\",\"Password\":\"suyj\"}";
```

Or use a JSON parser to create the parameters.

Comment: @user1261404, probably the uppercase `P` in Password.. Change it to `password` instead... Just a wild guess though...